# How to execute an external program with Perl (system) with arguments that include metacharacter "

Tags: perl

I am trying to execute an external program from perl code, namely cutadapt (https://cutadapt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide.html).

But I get an error message from cutadapt as soon as I add ;required which I want to have.

All the printed commands runs fine in the terminal.

My perl code is as follows:

```perl
#string without ;
my $cutadapt_cmd1 = '/home/USER/miniconda3/bin/cutadapt -a "GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA" --discard-untrimmed -q 20 -m 200 -o SAMPLE_NAME_401.IonXpress_0401.trim.fq IonXpress_0401_rawlib.basecaller.fq';
#string with ;
my $cutadapt_cmd2 = '/home/USER/miniconda3/bin/cutadapt -a "GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT;required...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA" --discard-untrimmed -q 20 -m 200 -o SAMPLE_NAME_401.IonXpress_0401.trim.fq IonXpress_0401_rawlib.basecaller.fq';
#array without ;
my @cutadapt_cmd3 = ('/home/USER/miniconda3/bin/cutadapt', '-a', 'GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA', '--discard-untrimmed' ,'-q' ,'20', '-m', '200', '-o' ,'SAMPLE_NAME_401.IonXpress_0401.trim.fq', 'IonXpress_0401_rawlib.basecaller.fq');
#array with ;
my @cutadapt_cmd4 = ('/home/USER/miniconda3/bin/cutadapt', '-a', 'GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT;required...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA', '--discard-untrimmed' ,'-q' ,'20', '-m', '200', '-o' ,'SAMPLE_NAME_401.IonXpress_0401.trim.fq', 'IonXpress_0401_rawlib.basecaller.fq');
#array with ; and with integers
my @cutadapt_cmd5 = ('/home/USER/miniconda3/bin/cutadapt', '-a', 'GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT;required...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA', '--discard-untrimmed' ,'-q' ,20, '-m', 200, '-o' ,'SAMPLE_NAME_401.IonXpress_0401.trim.fq', 'IonXpress_0401_rawlib.basecaller.fq');
#Works
print("\n\ncmd1\n\n");
system $cutadapt_cmd1;
#Fails
print("\n\ncmd2\n\n");
system $cutadapt_cmd2;
#Works
print("\n\ncmd3\n\n");
system @cutadapt_cmd3;
#Fails
print("\n\ncmd4\n\n");
system @cutadapt_cmd4;
#Fails
print("\n\ncmd5\n\n");
system @cutadapt_cmd5;
```

And the output looks like:

```py
cmd1

This is cutadapt 1.18 with Python 3.7.1
Command line parameters: -a GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA --discard-untrimmed -q 20 -m 200 -o SAMPLE_NAME_401.IonXpress_0401.trim.fq IonXpress_0401_rawlib.basecaller.fq
Processing reads on 1 core in single-end mode ...
Finished in 0.47 s (11 us/read; 5.67 M reads/minute).

=== Summary ===

Total reads processed:                  44,086
Reads with adapters:                         0 (0.0%)
Reads that were too short:               7,268 (16.5%)
Reads written (passing filters):             0 (0.0%)

Total basepairs processed:    11,458,046 bp
Quality-trimmed:                 371,723 bp (3.2%)
Total written (filtered):              0 bp (0.0%)

=== Adapter 2 ===

Sequence: GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA; Type: linked; Length: 25+21; 5' trimmed: 0 times; 3' trimmed: 0 times



cmd2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/bin/cutadapt", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cutadapt/__main__.py", line 741, in main
    pipeline = pipeline_from_parsed_args(options, paired, pair_filter_mode, quality_filename, is_interleaved_output)
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cutadapt/__main__.py", line 614, in pipeline_from_parsed_args
    adapters = adapter_parser.parse_multi(options.adapters, options.anywhere, options.front)
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cutadapt/adapters.py", line 335, in parse_multi
    adapters.extend(self.parse(spec, cmdline_type))
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cutadapt/adapters.py", line 322, in parse
    yield self._parse(spec, cmdline_type, name=None)
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cutadapt/adapters.py", line 237, in _parse
    name1, front1, sequence1, back1, parameters1 = self._parse_not_linked(spec1, 'front')
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cutadapt/adapters.py", line 170, in _parse_not_linked
    parameters = AdapterParser._parse_parameters(parameters_spec)
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cutadapt/adapters.py", line 132, in _parse_parameters
    raise KeyError('Unknown parameter {}'.format(key))
KeyError: 'Unknown parameter required'


cmd3

This is cutadapt 1.18 with Python 3.7.1
Command line parameters: -a GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA --discard-untrimmed -q 20 -m 200 -o SAMPLE_NAME_401.IonXpress_0401.trim.fq IonXpress_0401_rawlib.basecaller.fq
Processing reads on 1 core in single-end mode ...
Finished in 0.50 s (11 us/read; 5.27 M reads/minute).

=== Summary ===

Total reads processed:                  44,086
Reads with adapters:                         0 (0.0%)
Reads that were too short:               7,268 (16.5%)
Reads written (passing filters):             0 (0.0%)

Total basepairs processed:    11,458,046 bp
Quality-trimmed:                 371,723 bp (3.2%)
Total written (filtered):              0 bp (0.0%)

=== Adapter 2 ===

Sequence: GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA; Type: linked; Length: 25+21; 5' trimmed: 0 times; 3' trimmed: 0 times



cmd4

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/bin/cutadapt", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cutadapt/__main__.py", line 741, in main
    pipeline = pipeline_from_parsed_args(options, paired, pair_filter_mode, quality_filename, is_interleaved_output)
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cutadapt/__main__.py", line 614, in pipeline_from_parsed_args
    adapters = adapter_parser.parse_multi(options.adapters, options.anywhere, options.front)
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cutadapt/adapters.py", line 335, in parse_multi
    adapters.extend(self.parse(spec, cmdline_type))
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cutadapt/adapters.py", line 322, in parse
    yield self._parse(spec, cmdline_type, name=None)
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cutadapt/adapters.py", line 237, in _parse
    name1, front1, sequence1, back1, parameters1 = self._parse_not_linked(spec1, 'front')
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cutadapt/adapters.py", line 170, in _parse_not_linked
    parameters = AdapterParser._parse_parameters(parameters_spec)
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cutadapt/adapters.py", line 132, in _parse_parameters
    raise KeyError('Unknown parameter {}'.format(key))
KeyError: 'Unknown parameter required'


cmd5

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/bin/cutadapt", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cutadapt/__main__.py", line 741, in main
    pipeline = pipeline_from_parsed_args(options, paired, pair_filter_mode, quality_filename, is_interleaved_output)
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cutadapt/__main__.py", line 614, in pipeline_from_parsed_args
    adapters = adapter_parser.parse_multi(options.adapters, options.anywhere, options.front)
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cutadapt/adapters.py", line 335, in parse_multi
    adapters.extend(self.parse(spec, cmdline_type))
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cutadapt/adapters.py", line 322, in parse
    yield self._parse(spec, cmdline_type, name=None)
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cutadapt/adapters.py", line 237, in _parse
    name1, front1, sequence1, back1, parameters1 = self._parse_not_linked(spec1, 'front')
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cutadapt/adapters.py", line 170, in _parse_not_linked
    parameters = AdapterParser._parse_parameters(parameters_spec)
  File "/home/USER/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cutadapt/adapters.py", line 132, in _parse_parameters
    raise KeyError('Unknown parameter {}'.format(key))
KeyError: 'Unknown parameter required'
```

According to how I want to process my data, I really need to tell cutadapt that the adapters are required.

Comment: Does it work in the command line?

Comment: It does! And when I remove the ” it also works. But it does not what I want.

Comment: Strange I changed your command to echo to give `perl -e '@_ = ("echo","arg1\"","arg2");system( @_[0], @_ );'` and it works fine

Comment: Could it be that echo is bash and cutadapt is not? If that make sense.

Comment: Can you show the exact command line and the output when you run it in the shell (not perl)?

Comment: Unfortunately not now. But it would be about like this: ’cutadapt -a ”ATGC;required...TGCA;required” in_file

Comment: Also include the error you get.

Comment: The error comes from cutadapt complaining on missing argument. I think that it is python errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not reproduce your issue with a recent cutadapt version (cutadapt 2.5 with Python 3.7.3), installed using conda (cutadapt-2.5 package from bioconda channel). All 5 commands succeeded, giving the expected output (either 1 or 2 reads are trimmed, either 1 or 2 reads are written in the output). I used bash and zsh shells and perl v5.18.2 without an issue.
According to your output, you are using an older cutadapt version (cutadapt 1.18 with Python 3.7.1.).

**Try installing a recent cutadapt version** using conda, see directions below. This is the most likely cause of your issue.

*Installing cutadapt using conda* (assuming conda is already installed and bioconda is included in the channels):

```
conda update conda

conda search cutadapt

conda create --name cutadapt cutadapt

# Enable conda cutadapt environment:
source activate cutadapt

# ... run cutadapt ...

# At the end, exit the conda cutadapt environment:
source deactivate
```

*Running cutadapt from a perl script:*

```
cat > IonXpress_0401_rawlib.basecaller.fq <<EOF
@HWI-EAS209_0006_FC706VJ:5:58:5894:21141#ATCACG/1
GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCATAACAAGGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA
+
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
@HWI-EAS209_0006_FC706VJ:5:58:5895:21142#ATCACG/1
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA
+
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
EOF
```

Edit the script shown in your question:

- Remove the hardcoded cutadapt path (not needed using conda env).
- Change -m 200 to -m 2 to enable seeing differences in trimming for
  very short read examples.
- Print into STDOUT the output (trimmed) file contents.

  ./cutadapt.pl &> cutadapt.log

./cutadapt.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# string without ;
my $cutadapt_cmd1 = 'cutadapt -a "GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA" --discard-untrimmed -q 20 -m 2 -o SAMPLE_NAME_401.IonXpress_0401.trim.fq IonXpress_0401_rawlib.basecaller.fq';

# string with ;
my $cutadapt_cmd2 = 'cutadapt -a "GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT;required...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA" --discard-untrimmed -q 20 -m 2 -o SAMPLE_NAME_401.IonXpress_0401.trim.fq IonXpress_0401_rawlib.basecaller.fq';

# array without ;
my @cutadapt_cmd3 = ('cutadapt', '-a', 'GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA', '--discard-untrimmed' ,'-q' ,'20', '-m', '2', '-o' ,'SAMPLE_NAME_401.IonXpress_0401.trim.fq', 'IonXpress_0401_rawlib.basecaller.fq');

# array with ;
my @cutadapt_cmd4 = ('cutadapt', '-a', 'GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT;required...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA', '--discard-untrimmed' ,'-q' ,'20', '-m', '2', '-o' ,'SAMPLE_NAME_401.IonXpress_0401.trim.fq', 'IonXpress_0401_rawlib.basecaller.fq');

# array with ; and with integers
my @cutadapt_cmd5 = ('cutadapt', '-a', 'GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT;required...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA', '--discard-untrimmed' ,'-q' ,20, '-m', 2, '-o' ,'SAMPLE_NAME_401.IonXpress_0401.trim.fq', 'IonXpress_0401_rawlib.basecaller.fq');

# Works
print("\n\ncmd1\n\n");
system $cutadapt_cmd1;
system "cat SAMPLE_NAME_401.IonXpress_0401.trim.fq";

# Fails
print("\n\ncmd2\n\n");
system $cutadapt_cmd2;
system "cat SAMPLE_NAME_401.IonXpress_0401.trim.fq";

# Works
print("\n\ncmd3\n\n");
system @cutadapt_cmd3;
system "cat SAMPLE_NAME_401.IonXpress_0401.trim.fq";

# Fails
print("\n\ncmd4\n\n");
system @cutadapt_cmd4;
system "cat SAMPLE_NAME_401.IonXpress_0401.trim.fq";

# Fails
print("\n\ncmd5\n\n");
system @cutadapt_cmd5;
system "cat SAMPLE_NAME_401.IonXpress_0401.trim.fq";
```

cutadapt.log:

```
cmd1

This is cutadapt 2.5 with Python 3.7.3
Command line parameters: -a GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA --discard-untrimmed -q 20 -m 2 -o SAMPLE_NAME_401.IonXpress_0401.trim.fq IonXpress_0401_rawlib.basecaller.fq
WARNING: You specified a linked adapter as '-a ADAPTER1...ADAPTER2'. The
interpretation of what this means has changed in Cutadapt 2.0. (The 5'
adapter is now no longer anchored by default.) To get results consist
with the old behavior, you need to anchor the 5' adapter explicitly as
in '-a ^ADAPTER1...ADAPTER2'.
Processing reads on 1 core in single-end mode ...
Finished in 0.00 s (1803 us/read; 0.03 M reads/minute).

=== Summary ===

Total reads processed:                       2
Reads with adapters:                         2 (100.0%)
Reads that were too short:                   0 (0.0%)
Reads written (passing filters):             2 (100.0%)

Total basepairs processed:           152 bp
Quality-trimmed:                       0 bp (0.0%)
Total written (filtered):             85 bp (55.9%)

=== Adapter 1 ===

Sequence: GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA; Type: linked; Length: 25+21; 5' trimmed: 1 times; 3' trimmed: 2 times

No. of allowed errors:
0-9 bp: 0; 10-19 bp: 1; 20-25 bp: 2

No. of allowed errors:
0-9 bp: 0; 10-19 bp: 1; 20-21 bp: 2

Overview of removed sequences at 5' end
length  count   expect  max.err error counts
25  1   0.0 2   1



Overview of removed sequences at 3' end
length  count   expect  max.err error counts
21  2   0.0 2   2
@HWI-EAS209_0006_FC706VJ:5:58:5894:21141#ATCACG/1
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
+
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
@HWI-EAS209_0006_FC706VJ:5:58:5895:21142#ATCACG/1
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
+
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE


cmd2

This is cutadapt 2.5 with Python 3.7.3
Command line parameters: -a GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT;required...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA --discard-untrimmed -q 20 -m 2 -o SAMPLE_NAME_401.IonXpress_0401.trim.fq IonXpress_0401_rawlib.basecaller.fq
WARNING: You specified a linked adapter as '-a ADAPTER1...ADAPTER2'. The
interpretation of what this means has changed in Cutadapt 2.0. (The 5'
adapter is now no longer anchored by default.) To get results consist
with the old behavior, you need to anchor the 5' adapter explicitly as
in '-a ^ADAPTER1...ADAPTER2'.
Processing reads on 1 core in single-end mode ...
Finished in 0.00 s (1747 us/read; 0.03 M reads/minute).

=== Summary ===

Total reads processed:                       2
Reads with adapters:                         1 (50.0%)
Reads that were too short:                   0 (0.0%)
Reads written (passing filters):             1 (50.0%)

Total basepairs processed:           152 bp
Quality-trimmed:                       0 bp (0.0%)
Total written (filtered):             30 bp (19.7%)

=== Adapter 1 ===

Sequence: GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA; Type: linked; Length: 25+21; 5' trimmed: 1 times; 3' trimmed: 1 times

No. of allowed errors:
0-9 bp: 0; 10-19 bp: 1; 20-25 bp: 2

No. of allowed errors:
0-9 bp: 0; 10-19 bp: 1; 20-21 bp: 2

Overview of removed sequences at 5' end
length  count   expect  max.err error counts
25  1   0.0 2   1



Overview of removed sequences at 3' end
length  count   expect  max.err error counts
21  1   0.0 2   1
@HWI-EAS209_0006_FC706VJ:5:58:5894:21141#ATCACG/1
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
+
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE


cmd3

This is cutadapt 2.5 with Python 3.7.3
Command line parameters: -a GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA --discard-untrimmed -q 20 -m 2 -o SAMPLE_NAME_401.IonXpress_0401.trim.fq IonXpress_0401_rawlib.basecaller.fq
WARNING: You specified a linked adapter as '-a ADAPTER1...ADAPTER2'. The
interpretation of what this means has changed in Cutadapt 2.0. (The 5'
adapter is now no longer anchored by default.) To get results consist
with the old behavior, you need to anchor the 5' adapter explicitly as
in '-a ^ADAPTER1...ADAPTER2'.
Processing reads on 1 core in single-end mode ...
Finished in 0.00 s (1845 us/read; 0.03 M reads/minute).

=== Summary ===

Total reads processed:                       2
Reads with adapters:                         2 (100.0%)
Reads that were too short:                   0 (0.0%)
Reads written (passing filters):             2 (100.0%)

Total basepairs processed:           152 bp
Quality-trimmed:                       0 bp (0.0%)
Total written (filtered):             85 bp (55.9%)

=== Adapter 1 ===

Sequence: GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA; Type: linked; Length: 25+21; 5' trimmed: 1 times; 3' trimmed: 2 times

No. of allowed errors:
0-9 bp: 0; 10-19 bp: 1; 20-25 bp: 2

No. of allowed errors:
0-9 bp: 0; 10-19 bp: 1; 20-21 bp: 2

Overview of removed sequences at 5' end
length  count   expect  max.err error counts
25  1   0.0 2   1



Overview of removed sequences at 3' end
length  count   expect  max.err error counts
21  2   0.0 2   2
@HWI-EAS209_0006_FC706VJ:5:58:5894:21141#ATCACG/1
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
+
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
@HWI-EAS209_0006_FC706VJ:5:58:5895:21142#ATCACG/1
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
+
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE


cmd4

This is cutadapt 2.5 with Python 3.7.3
Command line parameters: -a GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT;required...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA --discard-untrimmed -q 20 -m 2 -o SAMPLE_NAME_401.IonXpress_0401.trim.fq IonXpress_0401_rawlib.basecaller.fq
WARNING: You specified a linked adapter as '-a ADAPTER1...ADAPTER2'. The
interpretation of what this means has changed in Cutadapt 2.0. (The 5'
adapter is now no longer anchored by default.) To get results consist
with the old behavior, you need to anchor the 5' adapter explicitly as
in '-a ^ADAPTER1...ADAPTER2'.
Processing reads on 1 core in single-end mode ...
Finished in 0.00 s (1732 us/read; 0.03 M reads/minute).

=== Summary ===

Total reads processed:                       2
Reads with adapters:                         1 (50.0%)
Reads that were too short:                   0 (0.0%)
Reads written (passing filters):             1 (50.0%)

Total basepairs processed:           152 bp
Quality-trimmed:                       0 bp (0.0%)
Total written (filtered):             30 bp (19.7%)

=== Adapter 1 ===

Sequence: GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA; Type: linked; Length: 25+21; 5' trimmed: 1 times; 3' trimmed: 1 times

No. of allowed errors:
0-9 bp: 0; 10-19 bp: 1; 20-25 bp: 2

No. of allowed errors:
0-9 bp: 0; 10-19 bp: 1; 20-21 bp: 2

Overview of removed sequences at 5' end
length  count   expect  max.err error counts
25  1   0.0 2   1



Overview of removed sequences at 3' end
length  count   expect  max.err error counts
21  1   0.0 2   1
@HWI-EAS209_0006_FC706VJ:5:58:5894:21141#ATCACG/1
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
+
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE


cmd5

This is cutadapt 2.5 with Python 3.7.3
Command line parameters: -a GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT;required...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA --discard-untrimmed -q 20 -m 2 -o SAMPLE_NAME_401.IonXpress_0401.trim.fq IonXpress_0401_rawlib.basecaller.fq
WARNING: You specified a linked adapter as '-a ADAPTER1...ADAPTER2'. The
interpretation of what this means has changed in Cutadapt 2.0. (The 5'
adapter is now no longer anchored by default.) To get results consist
with the old behavior, you need to anchor the 5' adapter explicitly as
in '-a ^ADAPTER1...ADAPTER2'.
Processing reads on 1 core in single-end mode ...
Finished in 0.00 s (1796 us/read; 0.03 M reads/minute).

=== Summary ===

Total reads processed:                       2
Reads with adapters:                         1 (50.0%)
Reads that were too short:                   0 (0.0%)
Reads written (passing filters):             1 (50.0%)

Total basepairs processed:           152 bp
Quality-trimmed:                       0 bp (0.0%)
Total written (filtered):             30 bp (19.7%)

=== Adapter 1 ===

Sequence: GAGGAAGTAAAAGTCRTAACAAGGT...ATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAA; Type: linked; Length: 25+21; 5' trimmed: 1 times; 3' trimmed: 1 times

No. of allowed errors:
0-9 bp: 0; 10-19 bp: 1; 20-25 bp: 2

No. of allowed errors:
0-9 bp: 0; 10-19 bp: 1; 20-21 bp: 2

Overview of removed sequences at 5' end
length  count   expect  max.err error counts
25  1   0.0 2   1



Overview of removed sequences at 3' end
length  count   expect  max.err error counts
21  1   0.0 2   1
@HWI-EAS209_0006_FC706VJ:5:58:5894:21141#ATCACG/1
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
+
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fantastic answer. I think that this solved it. I will post an explicit answer. Then click solved when I'm sure.

Comment: It still does not work! And I'm not being able to replicate the problem in a small scale. Please se my latest attemt.

Comment: Please include the **exact** command as you run it in the shell, and any errors (in the shell and in perl). The smaller the example, the better. Something similar to what I did in my answer. BTW, this: `cutadapt -a ”ATGC;required...TGCA;required” in_file` is too approximate, for example if you do not include fastq extension, cutadapt will fail. Also, `cutadapt complaining on missing argument` is not specific enough - what is the error exactly? Finally, why do you need the `"` quote? The precise command and error will help.

Comment: @OlovSvartström From the details that you added, it looks like the issue is different from my first guess. It could be related to cutadapt itself as you suggested.

Comment: Yes I did not realize the importance of being completely explicit. I have never come across this problem when executing a command within the code. But there is something with the ;

Comment: The problem is indeed due to different versions. Thanks to our messy installation perl calls an older version (1.18) of cutadapt while running exactly the same command in shell calls a newer (2.4). And only the newer excepts the parameter required! Thank you everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The following is the bourne shell command you are trying to execute:

```sh
cutadapt -a "ATGC;required...TGCA;required" in_file
```

To execute that, you need to pass the command to a bourne shell.

```
system('sh', '-c', 'cutadapt -a "ATGC;required...TGCA;required" in_file')
```

That can also be written as follows:

```
system('cutadapt -a "ATGC;required...TGCA;required" in_file')
```

The above command will spawn a shell and have it execute `cutadapt` with the following arguments:

- `cutadapt`
- `-a`
- `ATGC;required...TGCA;required`
- `in_file`

(Notice the lack of quotes.)

You can do the same directly from Perl as follows:

```
system('cutadapt', '-a', 'ATGC;required...TGCA;required', 'in_file')
```

This is better because it doesn't needlessly involve a shell.

Comment: I'm still not being able to get it work. Have a look at my latest real example.

Comment: `'-m 200'` should surely be `'-m', 200`. If that's not the only problem, please provide a command line that works from your shell ("terminal", "console").

Comment: Aha. And should integers be passed as integers and not strings? Both string variables are just to paste in the terminal and they work.

Comment: Program arguments can only be strings. If you pass a number, it will get stringified. `200` or `"200"` are therefore equivalent. The point of the comment is that `foo -m 200` passes three arguments: `foo`, `-m` and `200`. What you had was equivalent to the shell command `foo '-m 200'`, which only passes two: `foo` and `-m 200`.